# How to fill fast for integer number calculation?

Tags: excel

Ex. these are my number 302,179,260,757, 1046 and 667. I want to fill other column like 300,100,200, 700, 1000 and 600 for calculation. How to fill them fast? These are integer number.

I tried with flash fill already, but it doesn't work at all. what formula or function even tools that I want to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand. Is there a pattern to these numbers? Are they all going into the same column? How would we know which numbers to fill next?

Comment: What does "How to fill them fast?" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `FLOOR` formula:

```
=FLOOR(A1,100)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a simple math expression

```
=INT(A1/100)*100
```

where A1 is the cell to evaluate.